# Initialization of a return value should ignore constness of automatic object

Tags: c++, c++11, return, move-semantics, const-correctness

Adhering to const correctness, you might want to make your local object of type `unique_ptr` const as in the following, whereas `T` is some here unimportant type:

```
unique_ptr<T> foo() {
    const unique_ptr<T> p = make_unique<T>(...);
    ... using p's pointee ...
    return p;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't compile because the return value cannot be initialized, since `unique_ptr` has no copy constructor and the move constructor is not viable since `p` is const.

What about if the C++ standard would say that when the 'operand' of an return statement is an automatic object, then its potential constness is to be ignored? The automatic object cannot be referenced after the return value has been initialized, thus its constness is now irrelevant. In its destructor the const object can also be modified, so it's really just about defining where constness ends: just before the destructor or in this special case before the constructor of the return value.

However 'cannot be referenced' is not the entire truth: destructors of other locals, which are sequenced after initializing the return value, might reference it. But I think it's impossible that they care that the const object was modified. They got to know the object via pointer or reference to const, i.e. from their perspective they only know that they are not allowed to modify it, they can't know if others are allowed to modify it.

Do you think such a change to the C++ standard would be a good idea? Or do you see other solutions beside the one I gave below?

Just for the record: Non-solutions and other solutions:

- You can't `return unique_ptr<T>(p.get())` since now you have two `unique_ptr`s, each thinking it is the unique owner.
- You can't `return unique_ptr<T>(p.release())` since `p` is const and `release()` is a non-const member method.
- `return move(p)` is of no use since it does not remove constness and thus the move constructor still can't be called.
- Edit: As Chris Beck pointed out, also `return const_cast<unique_ptr<T>&&>(p)` is not a solution since modifying a const object is undefined behaviour (7.1.6.1 p4 in the standard N4140).

Comment: Surely another solution is to not make it const in the first place?

Comment: But then I have to give up const correctness for, from my current point of view, no good reason.

Comment: @FlorianKaufmann "Const correctness" to you means mutating a const object?

Comment: @immibis: I edited my question. It is about where constness ends. Already now the destructor of a const object can mutate it.

Comment: Const correctness usually applies to the function, not local variables.

Comment: If you want to modify the object by releasing it for the return value then it is not correct to make it const.

Comment: I think a standard change like you suggest would be a good idea. However I also think that the merit isn't enough to justify the effort. But if you want to write a proposal, nothing's stopping you :)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the benefit of `const unique_ptr<T>` is?

Comment: @M.M The same benefit of marking any local variable const. Some people argue const should me the default (as in SML).

Comment: do you want the shared pointer or the pointee const.
You could have also declared it as
shared_ptr<const T> p

Comment: @immibis So, why does the std allow "copy elision" (aka object confusion) for const objects?

Comment: In C++ if you use `const_cast` to cast away `const` from an object that was originally declared `const`, undefined behavior results. In effect what you are asking is that the compiler should remove the `const` for you when you are returning the object from a function in which it is a local variable. I wonder what are the consequences of this for the compiler? If it must always be "safe" to make a local variable which was `const` into `non-const` potentially later on, does this inhibit any optimizations? IIUC `const` is rarely connected to optimizations, but it's a complex topic.

Comment: The local `const` could point to the internal data of an object with a lifespan greater than the function. Removing the `const`ness in this case would be a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Since unique_ptr is a move-only type, returning by value will (hypothetically) call the move constructor for the returned value.
But since being moved from is a destructive operation, you can't really move from a const object.

But I think C++17's "guaranteed copy elision" (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) would help with this.
Basically, this would allow unmovable types to be returned by value from a function, such as your const unique_ptr.
Once again, I fear, you will have to wait for the new standard

Comment: I agree that what I actually want is the ability to express that the local object named `p` _is_ the return value - there shall be only one object, not two. I.e. I don't want to be forced to use the model that I need to initialize the return value with another object, here `p`. Copy elision as in the current standard does not help, since even with it, _conceptually_ there are still two objects, not one.

Answer (score 2):

I think such a change would be a bad idea. I sort of see where you are coming from but your solution to your problem would simply create a new problem that is currently solved.

I think we need to consider why we make objects `const` to begin with.

Its about safety and making sure the wrong thing does not happen to a given variable. By making a `unique_ptr` `const` you are actually saying that you don't want any *ownership* manipulation to occur on the object. You still get to manipulate the object it manages:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> foo()
{
    // const object means no calling non-const member functions
    // which means no changing the ownership of the managed pointer
    const std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>();

    // but we still get to manipulate the thing being pointed to:
    *p = 6;

    return std::move(p); // compile error - changing ownership
}
```

In this case you might want to make your `unique_ptr` `const` to prevent it accidentally being returned instead of another `unique_ptr` that you **do** want to return. Making the `unique_ptr` const actually prevents it from getting returned by mistake. So what we could do now is make all our `unique_ptr` objects `const` *except* the one whose *ownership* rights we want to return to the caller.

Your change would make that protection null and void and there would be less point in making the object `const` to begin with.

Comment: Agreed. Considering resource management classes, with const I really do want to express that the ownership shall not be modified for the lifetime of the object, i.e. up to the destructor call.